# Local Wordpress install with Remote Database. Error: Remote DB Appears to be already installed

Tags: wordpress, installation, local, development-environment

I am attempting to set up a local development environment for a wordpress site using a remote database.  One computer is a Mac and the other is running windows 8.  When I run this set up on the mac, the install completes and I am able to work interchangeably between the machines.  However, when I attempt to set up a new site on the windows machine, the install falters on the last step (where you enter the site name).

What I end up getting is a blank screen with a wordpress banner.  If I reload the page I get a "you appear to have already installed Wordpress" error.  When I go to the website address and try and log in, the username and password that I set up in the last step is not recognized.

I guess a temporary solution would be to set up all dev environments on the mac, however the windows machine is my main computer and I would like to be able to install properly from that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include 'http://' in your URL?

Refer : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/you-appear-to-have-already-installed-wordpress-1

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.  I entered "http://" in every url I could find in the install process.  however it didn't work.